# Excel JS - how to get data from a sheet and then send a GET request

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js, exceljs

I am trying to get a URL in cell `A1` in my sheet and send a GET request using that URL using ajax. However I could not make it works, ajax returns empty results.

```
Excel.run(async function(context) {
    var sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1");
    var range = sheet.getRange("A1");
    range.load("values");

    await context.sync().then( function() {
         var URL = range.values[0][0]
         $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: URL,
               success: function (data) {
                     console.log(data);
               },
               error: function(errorMessage) {
                   console.log(errorMessage);
                }
            })
    })
})
```

ajax works if I call it outside and before `await context.sync()....` but I need to put it inside otherwise `range.values[0][0]` would not be loaded yet and `URL` would be `undefined`.

Comment: `ajax returns empty results` means `data` is "empty"?

Comment: Please first figured out whether the request was sent out, and also ensure the url is right

Comment: Your code is mixing together two different ways of awaiting the `context.sync`. You are using the `await` keyword, but you have also appended a `then` method. You should not do both. Remove the `then` function. Immediately after `await context.sync();`, put the assignment to `URL` and the all of `ajax`.